# animateFloatAsState sometimes creates runtime type error on Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

The code below (`ImageFace()`) works very well nearly all of the time. However, some times, without any interaction at all, I will get a fatal error posted above. This happens when I leave my app running on the emulator for a few hours (but sometimes it happens instantly). And once I run the app again, the error again vanishes for the next few hours/days.

Part of the code that creates this error:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun ImageFace(image: String = "placeholder.png", onTap: () -> Unit = {}) {
    val selected = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val scale = animateFloatAsState(if (selected.value) 0.8f else 1f)

    Column(Modifier.scale(scale.value)) {
        Image(
            // other attributes
            modifier = Modifier
                .pointerInteropFilter {
                    when (it.action) {
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                            selected.value = true
                        }

                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                            selected.value = false
                            onTap()
                        }
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                            selected.value = false
                        }
                    }
                    true
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Said error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
        at com.example.simplephone.LiveLiterals$MainActivityKt.Float$else$if$arg-0$call-animateFloatAsState$val-scale$fun-ImageFace(Unknown Source:31)
        at com.example.simplephone.MainActivityKt.ImageFace(MainActivity.kt:323)
```

To the extent that I understand, this could be an issue with `animateFloatAsState` not always returning `State<Float>`. But I'm new to this environment, so it is very likely that I'm not using this as intended.

Also the `MainActivity.kt:323` is a random line number inside MainActivity which changes each time this error occurs. Debugging this has been impossible since it happens super randomly. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Android Studio resources got mixed, try to do next:
**Build -> Clean Project -> Rebuild Project**

Comment: Thanks, will try. Is there any reason why resources getting mixed up causes type errors?